# iOS Expo Calendar Issue

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-calendars, expo-calendar

this app is missing NSCalendersFullAccessUsageDescription, so calender methods will fail. add this key to your bundle's Info.plist

I am using Expo SDK 50. I am trying to Use Expo Calendar to Add Events to My Calendar. Whenever I Am Trying to Run My Code It Showing this Error.

The Required NSCalendersFullAccessUsageDescription already available in Info.plist file.

Expo Calendar Working Fine In Android But I don't know why it's not working in iOS.

This Is My Code,

```
import * as Calendar from "expo-calendar";

const VisitorHome = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const { status } = await Calendar.requestCalendarPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === "granted") {
      const calendars = await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync(
        Calendar.EntityTypes.EVENT
      );
      console.log("Here are all your calendars:");
      console.log({ calendars });
    }
  })();
}, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header headerName="Home" />
      <View flex={1} bg="$black"></View>
    </>
  );
};

export default VisitorHome;
```

Can Someone please give any solution or suggestion. so that i can resolve and move forward.

Please give me answer with some Code.

If you are using another version of expo then Please mention.

I hope i'll get answer.

I tried Different react-native libraries like react-native-calendar-event, react-native-calendar-events but it's not working.

I have tried to downgrade expo from 50 to 59, 48 but in that case also expo calendar not working.